# Gmail event registration mark up not working

Tags: email, gmail, schema.org, json-ld, google-schemas

I am trying to test gmail event registration email mark up from [google dev docs](https://developers.google.com/gmail/markup/reference/event-reservation), But it is not adding any event on google calendar.

For testing I am using [google app script](https://script.google.com). I am using my personal gmail ID which contain @gmail.com

Following is the script tag which is validated by [Email Markup Tester](https://www.google.com/webmasters/markup-tester/u/0/)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="application/ld+json">
        {
            "@context": "http://schema.org",
            "@type": "EventReservation",
            "reservationNumber": "E123456789",
            "reservationStatus": "http://schema.org/Confirmed",
            "underName": {
                "@type": "Person",
                "name": "John Smith"
            },
            "reservationFor": {
                "@type": "Event",
                "name": "Foo Fighters Concert",
                "startDate": "2027-03-06T19:30:00-08:00",
                "performer": {
                    "@type": "Organization",
                    "name": "The Foo Fighters",
                    "image": "http://www.amprocktv.com/wp-content/uploads/2027/01/foo-fighters-1-680x383.jpg"
                },
                "location": {
                    "@type": "Place",
                    "name": "AT&T Park",
                    "address": {
                        "@type": "PostalAddress",
                        "streetAddress": "24 Willie Mays Plaza",
                        "addressLocality": "San Francisco",
                        "addressRegion": "CA",
                        "postalCode": "94107",
                        "addressCountry": "US"
                    }
                }
            },
            "modifiedTime": "2027-05-01T08:00:00-08:00",
            "modifyReservationUrl": "http://united.com/modifyreservation.html"
        }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>Event Reservation Example</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Please help me to find out where I am making mistake or is there any issue with schema mark up.
Or Do I need to register with google while I am using [google app script](https://script.google.com).